# Proof about sets with no maximum: show the distance between two functions is a metric

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

My topology book asks me to prove that the distance property defined on pairs of functions below is a metric. The definition of the property involves the concept of least upper bound, presumably in order to encompass functions which do not have a maximum or minimum. THe first three properties of a metric are easy to demonstrate. I have difficulty with the last one.

For functions bounded on [a,b], the distance is defined as $d(f,g)$ =l.u.b. $\cup_{x\in [a,b]} \{|f(x)-g(x)|\}$

It is required to prove that $d(f,h)\le d(f,g)+d(g,h)$.

If $|f(x)-h(x)|$ has a maximum then the proof is easy:

$d(f,h)=|f(c)-h(c)|\le |f(c)-g(c)|+|g(c)-h(c)|\le d(f,g)+d(g,h)$

Actually, I don't have an example of a function pair whose absolute difference has no maximum on a closed interval.

Here is my attempt at proof using the least upper bound concept:

$\forall \epsilon\gt 0,\exists x\in [a,b]$ such that $|f(x)-h(x)| + \epsilon \gt d(f,h)$

$|f(x)-h(x)|\le |f(x)-g(x)|+|g(x)-h(x)| \le d(f,g)+d(g,h)$

$\forall \epsilon \gt 0$,  $d(f,h)-\epsilon \lt d(f,g)+d(g,h)$

$d(f,h)\le d(f,g)+d(g,h)$

Is this a correct way of dealing with least upper bound and solving the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from a $<$ that should be a $\le$ in your third last line of mathematics, this is all perfectly valid. If you want to expand the implication from the second last line to your last line, suppose for the sake of contradiction that $d(f, h) > d(f, g) + d(g, h)$, and let $\varepsilon = d(f, h) - d(f, g) - d(g, h) > 0$. This will lead to a contradiction.

If you want an example where this maximum is not achieved, take $f(x) = \arctan(x)$, and $g(x) = 0$. Then the supremal value of $|f(x) - g(x)|$ is $\pi/2$, but it is never achieved (and only approached via the two horizontal asymptotes).